# A problem on the space of sequences

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the following sequence of sequences :

$x_{0}:=\{0,0,0,0......\}$,$x_{1}:=\{0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2}.......\}$ (i.e $0,\frac{1}{2}$ repeated infinitely), $x_{2}:=\{0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}.0.......\}$ (i.e $0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}$ repeated infinitely),........,$x_{n}:=\{0,\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{2}{n+1},\frac{3}{n+1},...\frac{n}{n+1},0,.......\}$ (i.e $0,\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{2}{n+1},\frac{3}{n+1},...\frac{n}{n+1}$ repeated infinitely)

Define $\mathcal H:=$ Set  of all complex valued sequences say $\{a_{n}\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|^{2}}{n(n+1)} < \infty$.

Is it true $\{1,1,1,...\}$ (i.e all 1's) belongs to closed linear span of $\{x_{n}\}\subset \mathcal H$

Comment: What is your norm? If it's the sup norm, for instance, then $\{ 1, 1, 1, \dots \}$ certainly doesn't lie in the (closure of the) linear span of the $x_n$, since each $x_n$ has a zero entry and so lies at distance 1 from $\{ 1, 1, 1, \dots \}$.

Comment: I assume the norm is the weighted Hilbert space norm, i.e., $\|a\|^2=\sum |a_n|^2/(n(n+1))$. Clive's comment still applies: everything in the closed linear span will have the leading zero.

Comment: @Leonid Kovalev : Your assumption is correct norm is weighted Hilbert space norm.

Comment: @CliveNewstead Could you consider crafting that comment into an answer, so that this question may disappear from the Unanswered queue?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Done

Answer (score 1):

This very belated answer is posted as per Lord_Farin's request - see the comments on the question.

- If you're using the sup norm then $(1, 1, \dots, )$ doesn't belong to the closed linear span because all the $x_n$s have a $0$ in them and hence $\left\|x_n-(1,1,\dots)\right\| \ge 1$ (in fact, $=1$); and...
- Even if you're using the Hilbert norm, since the first term of all the $x_n$s is $0$, the distance is still $\ge 1$.